# IIS Website With SQL Server Express

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, iis, iis-7.5

Is their a setting in IIS that needs to be set-up?  I have my site writing details to a SQL Server Express table before the page is "finished" which works to perfection when I test locally or even if I run internally from within my network.  BUT if I access the page from any device outside of the computer it is hosted on, NOTHING will be written to the sql server table?

Comment: Are you getting any errors, if you are what is it?

Comment: @DonJayamanne - i have the writetosql in a try/catch block so no error is displayed.  Does iis capture the error?